# Как сделать раздел на сайте с вложенными страницами в url?

Tags: php, ссылки, index, раздел, веб-сайт

Искал в поиске тут ответ на мой вопрос, но либо плохо искал, либо реально ответа нет.
Переписываю сайт, но с подобным ещё не сталкивался в силу недостаточной опытности и знаний.

И так, есть в главном файле сайта index.php ниже представленный код и в этот код ниже мы дописываем ссылки которые будут на сайте:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    $Page = 'index';
    $Module = 'index';
} else {
    $URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
    $Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
    $Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);

    if (!empty($Module)) {
        $Param = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
            $Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
        }
    }
}

if ($Page == 'index') {
    include 'page/index.php';
} elseif ($Page == 'teplo') {
    include 'page/teplo.php';
}
```

При таком раскладе имеется папка **page** в которой лежат страницы сайта и соответственно в адресной строке браузера мы видим такое: **[https://мойсайт.ру/teplo](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/teplo)**

Но если мы хотим видеть например вот такую ссылку **[https://мойсайт.ру/catalog/teplota1](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/catalog/teplota1)** то ничего не работает, а браузер с таким кодом пишет что страницы не существует.

Короче вопрос: КАК СДЕЛАТЬ КАТАЛОГ (типа раздел сайта с товарами) на PHP, чтобы в адресной строке мы видели ссылки такого вида: **[https://мойсайт.ру/catalog/teplota1](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/catalog/teplota1)**

Comment: в гугле: "простой роутинг для сайта на php"